# Bad shadows in custom mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to generate a custom mesh (I'm a beginner in unity). I tried to create an easy figure to demonstrate this effect. I create vertices and triangles and set them on the mesh:

```
List<int> triangles;
List<Vector3> vertices;
Mesh mesh;
public void Create() {
    ...
    mesh.SetVertices(vertices);
    mesh.SetTriangles(triangles, 0);
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
}
```

There are no duplicated vertices or triangles and I use a standard shader for the material.
[image: bad shadows]
1: What are the lines?
2,3: What are the strange shadows on the big edges (about 135 degrees between triangles)?
What could be the cause of this? Or it is normal.
Thank you.

Upd. I know that this problem is in area of shaders. And for 3d figures normals map (may be) solves the problem. But what should I do if I want to procedurally generate any figure?

Comment: This thread might help https://forum.unity.com/threads/procedural-mesh-shadow-issue.485312/